# Google Cloud Storage Object Change Notification sends notification even after responding with status 200

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I have object change notification enabled for my cloud storage bucket. I understand that due to retry mechanism it will deliver more than one notification. But it retries indefinitely which eats up my appengine frontend instance hours(I have 6 notification activated in my application).

I also notice that the subsequent notification does not have proper headers.

Is this a right behaviour?

My code to handle the notification is as follows.

```
LOG.info("received notification");
    String resourceId=req.getHeader("X-Goog-Resource-Id");
    String channelId=req.getHeader("X-Goog-Channel-Id");
    LOG.info("channel id::"+channelId);
    LOG.info("resource id::"+resourceId);       

    if(null == req.getHeader("X-Goog-Resource-State") || req.getHeader("X-Goog-Resource-State").equals("not_exists")){
        LOG.severe("invalid resource_statestate::"+req.getHeader("X-Goog-Resource-State"));
        resp.setStatus(resp.SC_OK);
        return;
    }

    StringBuffer buf=new StringBuffer();
    String line=null;
    BufferedReader read=req.getReader();        
    while((line=read.readLine()) != null){
        buf.append(line);
    }       
    JSONObject jsonObject =new JSONObject(buf.toString());      
    if(!jsonObject.has("name") || !jsonObject.has("bucket")){
        LOG.severe("File or bucket name is not available:"+jsonObject.get("bucket")+"/"+jsonObject.get("name"));
        resp.setStatus(resp.SC_OK);
        return;         
    }           
     //required logics
   resp.setStatus(resp.SC_OK);
```

Comment: Are the channel id and resource id identical for the duplicate notifications?

Comment: I dont have any duplicate notification. I have notification enabled for 6 different buckets. So the channel id and resource id are identical for each notification.

Comment: I think you'll need to clarify what you mean by "it retries indefinitely", also "it doesn't have proper headers". What exactly are you observing, and what do you expect to see?

Comment: Any updates on my questions?